# SharePoint online modern experience hide suiteBar, left navigation and top ribbon using SPFX showing it for few second then its hide

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, css, modern-experience, spfx-extensions

I am hiding suiteBar, left navigation and top ribbon using SPFX extension but for few second its showing up.

I don't want to show it for few second also.

I tried to hide it from master page alternate CSS also but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding these elements using CSS is unsupported:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages

On modern team sites, quick launch can be hidden by going to Site Settings > Navigation Elements > untick the "Enable Quick Launch" option.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use code to alter (move, hide) the Suite Bar within your application.
[image]
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/portal-branding#office-365-suite-bar

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the left navigation by going into the site settings > Navigation Elements > Uncheck the Flag "Enable Quick Launch"

If this doesnt work, then you also need to delete the links in the Navigation Section.

Comment: 1. This doesn't work on Modern pages anymore, just classic pages.

2. Deleting links is NOT a solution.

Comment: Deleting the links does work !

Comment: I really don't want to get into a back and forth with you. Even if you delete EVERY link, you STILL have an area of white space to the left where the Quick Launch is. It is NOT an effective solution.

Comment: If something works for someone, it can be helpful for somebody else as well, if you need help you can ask!

Comment: The Quick launch control is configured in such a way that the white space is automatically hidden when there are no links in it. so the white space problem shouldnt show. the other solution is hiding using custom css ,

Comment: Custom CSS? Maybe you should go back and read the question. This is for a modern page. No CSS. No JavaScript. Just whatever Microsoft permits us to drop on the page.